# test class for trigger where i am calculating contacts created by every user

Tags: code-coverage, code

I have written this trigger and trying to write the test class but the code coverage is not happening. Can anybody suggest where i am missing something?

```
Trigger Benchmarks on Recruitment_Benchmark__c (before insert, before update) {
    Set<id>rid=new set<id>(); 
    Date Fdate;  
    Date Tdate;
    Integer interviewshappened; 
    Integer Psourced;
    Integer Alist;  
        for (Recruitment_Benchmark__c BM: trigger.new){

            rid.add(BM.Recruiter_Name__c);
            Fdate= BM.From_Date__c;
            Tdate=BM.To_Date__c;

        }

     Psourced=[select count() from contact where ownerid IN:rid AND CreatedDate >=: Fdate AND CreatedDate<=:Tdate ];
     Alist=[select count() from SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c where ownerid IN:rid AND CreatedDate >=: Fdate AND CreatedDate<=:Tdate];  
     interviewshappened=[select count() from SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c where ownerid IN:rid AND CreatedDate >=: Fdate AND CreatedDate<=:Tdate];

    for(Recruitment_Benchmark__c BM: trigger.new){

        BM.profiles_sourced__c= Psourced;
        BM.placements_done__c= Alist;
        BM.interviews_happened__c=interviewshappened;

    } 

}
```

test class:

```
    @Istest
    public class Benchmarks_Testclass{
        static testMethod void testBenchmarks(){

            User[] user = [select Id,LastName,FirstName,Alias,
                                    Email, EmailEncodingKey, LanguageLocaleKey,
                                    LocaleSidKey, TimeZoneSidKey, Username
                                    from User limit 2];
            Recruitment_Benchmark__c RB = new Recruitment_Benchmark__c();
                    RB.Recruiter_Name__c='00541000002BhVw';
                   RB.From_Date__c = system.today();
                  RB.To_Date__c = system.today();       

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your test class does not have `test visibility true`, you have to follow the following steps -

1. You have to create a user in your test class.
2. You need to create record for `contact`, `SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c` and `SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c` in Your test  class, where -
   ownerId of these three records must be equal to test user id, as equal to your `Recruiter_Name__c` of `Recruitment_Benchmark__c`.

   3. You need to set your `Recruiter_Name__c` of `Recruitment_Benchmark__c` with one of the 2 users you have created as test data.
   4. Then insert your `Recruitment_Benchmark__c`.